# how to bisect_plane with use_fill = True in Blender 2.79 using python?

Tags: python

I need to cut mesh in 2 pieces using filling cutted edge. But there is no parameter use_fill in bisect_plane in blender 2.79. I have a function that make cut:

```
def cut_figure(obj, plane_co, plane_no):
   bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj)
   geom = bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:] + bm.faces[:]
   ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=geom, plane_co=plane_co, plane_no=plane_no)
   #next line will call TypeError: bisect_plane: keyword "use_fill" is invalid for this operator
   ret = bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=geom, plane_co=plane_co, plane_no=plane_no, use_fill = True)
   bmesh.ops.split_edges(bm, edges=[e for e in ret['geom_cut'] if isinstance(e, bmesh.types.BMEdge)])
```

I've found bpy.ops.mesh.bisect method but it is not so usefull.

Answer (score 0):

**Boolean Modifier**

Can use the `clear_inner` or `clear_outer` property of the bisect plane operator, and run twice, grid fill the returned cut(s).

However it may be much simpler to script this approach

[image]

- add a plane at cutting coordinates
- scale the plane such that it completely encapsulates mesh to be cut (sphere in example image)
- give the plane thickness with solidify modifier, once again making sure it completely encaps cuttee mesh.
- add a boolean modifier (difference)  to the object to be cut, using plane as target.
- apply the modifier and save result.
- redo with the plane normal flipped (other half).
- the resultant filled face will be an ngon(s).